# Базы данных в C#

Tags: c#, база-данных

Начинаю работать с бд в c#. Раньше с бд не сталкивался, но принцип работы понимаю. С чего начать полегче? Пока надо сделать простые операции: добавить, изменить и такого типа. Читаю про LINQ to SQL. Или есть что-то попроще?

Comment: проще нету, есть эффективнее - ``Stored Procedure``

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если Вы с бд раньше не сталкивались и возможно понимаете только принципы, то начинать сразу с LINQ to SQL не рекомендую, для начала ознакомтесь с основами.

Работа с SQL: [Основы SQL](http://www.intuit.ru/department/database/sql/) и [Язык запросов SQL](http://sql-language.ru/)

Работа с ADO : [FAQ для раздела “ADO.NET и базы данных”](http://www.cyberforum.ru/ado-net/thread182279.html)

Comment: Хорошо, буду изучать.

Answer (score 2):

То, о чем вы спрашиваете, это ORM, т.е. системы, отображающие реляционные штуки на объектные и обратно. "Из коробки" есть выбор из трех вариантов (надеюсь, ничего не упустил):

1. LINQ to SQL - в общем случае, действительно, по-проще, т.к. не содержит ничего кроме самого базового и этого в большинстве случаев хватает.
2. ADO.NET Entity Framework - особо удобно, если делать WPF проект в VS.
3. ADO.NET DataSet - особо удобно, если делать WinForms проект в VS.

В целом, по моему опыту, ORM - это всегда несложно. Трудности возникают не в том коде, к-ый непосредственно с ORM связан (т.е. DAL - слой доступа к данным), а в остальном, работающем с DAL. Чтобы избежать их, желательно немного изучить какой-нибудь паттерн, подходящий под технологию (MVC, MVP, MVVM, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Есть [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb399572.aspx).
Так же существуют другие сторонние [ORM](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM).